# bind web audio context event back to react component

Tags: reactjs, web-audio-api

I'm building a little audio player in react using Web Audio API.

I have a play button that shows different styles depending on whether the content is playing, or stopped.

But I'm not sure how to bind the events of the audio context back to the component so I can set the state of the button.

```
 play = () => {
     if(audioCtx.state === 'running' && this.state.started) {
      audioCtx.suspend().then(function() {

        //HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO SET STATE buttonOn
       //but the "this" is not recognized

      });
    } else if(audioCtx.state === 'suspended') {
      audioCtx.resume().then(function() {
        this.setState({buttonOn = true});  <== "this" not recognized
      });
    } else {
      this.playNext(0);
      this.setState({started: true});
      buttonOn = true;
    }
  }
```

How to get back to the component's "this" from these events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consider that this method is in your class component.

change your callback functions to arrow functions

```
 play = () => {
     if(audioCtx.state === 'running' && this.state.started) {
      audioCtx.suspend().then(() => {

      });
    } else if(audioCtx.state === 'suspended') {
      audioCtx.resume().then(() => {
        this.setState({buttonOn: true});
      });
    } else {
      this.playNext(0);
      this.setState({started: true});
      buttonOn = true;
    }
  }
```

Comment: This didn't work.  It didn't do anything.  I have audioCtx defined OUTSIDE the component.  Does that matter?

Comment: Where is the `play` method defined ? can you make a simple working example on [codesandbox](http://www.codesandbox.io/s/new) ?

Comment: My bad.  Your solution works.  I'd forgotten to reset the style.  Thanks for your help!